# UIViewController does not deallocate after presenting another one

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I can't understand why the `vc1` is not deallocating after presenting another one

```
var vc1: UIViewController! = UIViewController()
weak var weakVc1 = vc1

vc1.present(UIViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
vc1.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

vc1 = nil

print(weakVc1)
```

If I remove `present:animated:completion` call, then it will print `nil`, but in the above scenario `vc1` is still here and not deallocating. This means that some other object has a strong reference to the `vc1`
I ran this expamle in playground and inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Both give the same results.

Also I tried to present `vc1` from some initial view controller at first which was instantiated from storyboard and in this case I got `nil` everytime.

Also I tried to wait for completions in both `present` and `dismiss` but nothing helps.

So I thought it can be some `UIWindow` instance that hold the reference. But if I make `vc1` a root for some `UIWindow` (and event make it key and visible) it will still NOT deallocate.

Memory graph shows that there is a reference from `VM Stack Thread 0` and some `malloc` but to be honest I don't understand what it means

Is it a memory leak and is there any way to deallocate this view controller?

Comment: I think when you present it still holds a strong ref to vc1 since you presented it to itself. if you want you can have like a main controller having both? then present the vcs on the mainController instead of vc1

Comment: What do you mean "presented it to itself"? I don't need to present both, I want just to test one controller presenting another, so I will test another behaviour if I introduce  mainViewController and present from it.